# demonstration of $\sigma$- *algebra*

Tags: real-analysis

is it correct? If not, please help me correct it.

prove that "an Algebra A is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if, it is closed under increasing countable unions,".
that is;

$ \{E_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset{}A$ and $E_n \subset{}E_{n+1}$ for all $n \in {}N$ then
$\displaystyle\cup_{n=1}^\infty{} E_n \in{}A$

Demonstration:

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra over $X$ that is closed under increasing countable unions. An arbitrary sequence of sets $ \{ A_n \}_{n=1}^{ \infty} \subset{} \mathcal{A} $ is chosen and the sequence $ \{ E_n \}_{n=1}^{ \infty}$ defined by

$$E_n = \bigcup _{k=1}^{n}A_n$$

Now, $E_n \subseteq{}E_{n+1}$ and $E_n \in \mathcal {A} $ for all $n \geq{}1$ since $\mathcal {A}$ is an algebra as well

$$\bigcup_ {n=1}^{ \infty} A_n = \bigcup_ {n=1}^{ \infty} E_n \in \mathcal {A}$$

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, it is already fully demonstrated? I appreciate your response

Comment: Yes, your proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks, very much

Comment: How else can this demonstration of the exercise be done? you can do it?